# Is it possible to connect to Azure Table Storage from Excel?

Tags: excel, azure-table-storage, adodb

We have an Excel file where we connect to our SQL Server to retrieve sales data using the below VBA code. Now we want to use Azure Table Storage to store sales data and feed our Excel from there. Is it possible to do that? I mean is it possible to connect to an Azure Table Storage with ADODB?

```
Sub UpdateSales()

  Dim objMyConn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim objMyRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

  objMyConn.CommandTimeout = 720
  objMyConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.20.1.100;Initial Catalog=ofix;User ID=xxx;Password=yyy"
  objMyRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM [OFIX].[dbo].[OFIX_SALES]", objMyConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

  Set ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sales").PivotCache.Recordset = objMyRecordset
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sales").PivotCache.Refresh

  objMyRecordset.Close
  objMyConn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's quite old but hopefully, my comment might help somehow. I ran into the kinda same situation. I don't think `ADODB` can connect to Azure table storage. What I did is to use some VBA forms and make HTTP requests to an API (here I use Azure Function. This has a great integration with Azure Table).  Then Azure Function makes the CRUD things towards the Azure Table. An extra layer to work with but that how I managed to.. connect Excel with Azure Table.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using powerquery? This is a From operation.

Excel 2016 +

> On the Data tab, click Get Data > From Azure > From Azure Table
>   Storage. If you don't see the Get Data button, click New Query > From
>   Azure > From Microsoft Azure Table Storage.

Excel 2010 (some editions) & 2013

> In the Power Query ribbon tab, click From Azure > From Microsoft Azure
>   Table Storage. Follow the additional steps below.

[Full details](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-microsoft-azure-table-storage-power-query-4ba56e50-2c4c-468e-887c-8de9b49fd22e#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2010_%E2%80%93_2013)

If you are interested in pulling into Azure can you provide more details? There are services with more info in documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/).

Interesting article [here.](https://codehollow.com/2016/10/working-with-azure-table-storage-and-excel/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this method. We have two issues with this: 1) the data is loaded into the sheet instead of the recordset 2) we couldn't find a way to update it programatically (I mean triggering our UpdateSales sub from a button.) If anyone has knowledge on how to solve issue #2 we will be very happy.